# Uploading to imgur with javascript

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write some javascript that lets a user upload a file to imgur.  The first step for me is to just load an image from my webserver (publicly available) and try to upload that using my api key.  Here's what I have so far:

```
self.uploadImage = function upload(file) {
        debugger;
        file = $.get("../../Content/images/icon.png", function () {
            alert("success");
        })
        .done(function () { alert("second success"); })
        .fail(function () { alert("error"); })
        .always(function () { alert("finished"); });

        // file is from a <input> tag or from Drag'n Drop
        // Is the file an image?

        if (!file || !file.type.match(/image.*/)) return;  // fails here

        // It is!
        // Let's build a FormData object

        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("image", file); // Append the file
        fd.append("key", "<my key>");

        // Create the XHR 
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json");
        xhr.onload = function() {
            // The URL of the image is:
            JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).upload.links.imgur_page;
        };

        // And now, we send the formdata
        xhr.send(fd);
        debugger;
    };
```

I can't get past the first `if` statement though - I get an error that says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined

I do get the success alerts from the .get...  I'm not sure how to debug this further as I'm a bit new to js... any help would be much appreciated.

at the if statement:

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `file.type`? Or better yet, what is the `typeof file.type`?

Comment: @ChristopherW I get typeof file.type is "undefined" and typeof file is "object" - I'll take a screenshot

Comment: There's your answer. `match` is a string method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `file.type` is undefined. The reason for this is that you are using the return value of the [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) function incorrectly. This function returns a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object which does not have a `type` property.

Comment: but it should be defined... hence my problem

Comment: What makes you think it should be defined? I cannot find this property in the jQuery documentation of the jqXHR object.

Comment: file is defined in the third line of my code... I'm following this: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/03/the-shortest-image-uploader-ever/

Comment: `file` is assigned the return value of `$.get()` in line 3. The return value of this function is a `jqXHR` object and this object does not have a type property. You even copied the comment that tells you what to do: `file` needs to be supplied from an input box or drag and drop. Have a look at the [live example source](http://paulrouget.com/miniuploader) of your tutorial to see how they supply the files.